# Not able to install Ldapclient on a non-internet connected PC

Tags: 10.10, openldap

For past couple of days am trying to install ldapclient in ubuntu 10.10, but no luck.

Can anyone point me to the exact packages i need to download and install, i have tried the same so may times but failed, so please help.

One important thing is that i dont have any internet connection to this desktop because of security reasons, so i need to download those packages and install manually.

Comment: To download ANYTHING from ANYWHERE you have to have Internet connectivity, so either you connect your computer or download the packages from another computer and then install them.

Answer (score 2):

If [this](http://tuxnetworks.blogspot.com/2010/04/ldap-client-lucid-lynx.html) guide is correct, you need to install these: `libpam-ldap; libnss-ldap; nss-updatedb; libnss-db; nscd; ldap-utils`

To download them and their dependencies, use [APT-Web](http://apt-web.dahsy.at/). Select your Ubuntu version, then your distro. After that, paste this into the packages input field: `libpam-ldap; libnss-ldap; nss-updatedb; libnss-db; nscd; ldap-utils` Click submit. It will display what packages need to be downloaded. Download them and use some media to get them to the machine that isn't connected to the internet. Then just use dpkg to install them. `dpkg -i *` will install all packages in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Along with all of these you would definitely need libldap. libldap-2.4.2 is the most recent one if I'm  not mistaken. Installing libpam-ldap, libnss-ldap and libkrb53 (for Kerberos related authentication). The package ldap-auth-config should help you in setting up the ldap configuration.

All these .deb files can be installed individually using 'dpkg --install'. Use the 'force-depends' parameter to ignore dependencies so that you don't have to strictly follow a chronological order to install the packages. 'ldap-utils' will give you utilities like ldapsearch that will help you determine whether ldap is functioning properly. Use 'ldapsearch -x' to ensure that LDAP client can bind to the ldap master server.